# Using both Strings and Integers in one list separately?

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list of various lists:

```
input_data = [['min',1,2,3,5,6],['max',1,2,3,5,6]]
```

The lists always start with `strings` of `3 characters long`, followed by a list of `integers`.

How do I determine the `minimum(smallest) integer` of the list that starts with `min` and the `maximum (largest) integer of the list that starts with 'max'`?

The lists are saved in one variable 'input_data', so I don't know how to access both lists separately.

For instance:

```
   for i in input_data:
       if 'min' in input_data:
          answer = "The minimum number of the list is" + str(min(input_data))

   if 'max' in input_data:
      answer = "The maximum number of the list is" + str(max(input_data))

print answer
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if 'min' or 'max' are always the first entry of the list you could do this:

```
for sublist in input_data:

    if 'min' == sublist[0]:
        answer = "The minimum number of the list {} is {}".format(
                sublist[1:], min(sublist[1:]))
    elif 'max' == sublist[0]:
        answer = "The maximum number of the list {} is {}".format(
                sublist[1:], max(sublist[1:]))

    print answer
```

note that you should exclude the strings 'max/min' when looking for the maximal/minimal integer.

Comment: Thank you so much hiro, this will really help. Have a great day, and thank you for your time

Comment: Just one more question hiro: If I want to print out the answer for both, how do I do it? I want to print out both answers, because both are true, so I don't want the If or else, rather if min print this the answer and if max print the answer as well... Do you think I must make "answer" into separate variables e.g min_answer, max_answer?

Comment: i put the `print` statement inside the for loop. this does indeed print both answers.

Comment: Nevermind, I tested the code you gave me and it worked, I thank you again! :)  edit : yes, I just saw, thank you hiro!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again hiro, but I have one final question if you don't mind: If i want to display the list of numbers, how do I do it: e.g.. "the maximum number in the list [1,2,3,5,6] is 9..." (the list that 'max' starts with). Is it: "The maximum number of the list" + str(sublist[1:]) + "is {}".format(max(sublist[1:]))

Comment: Thanks hiro, it's working! :) Final Final question, and I wont bother you again. If i have two lists that start with 'max'.. how do I approach this problem? because now it only prints out one of the lists that start with 'max'? Sorry for the bother e.g.. [['min',1,2,3,5,6],['max',1,2,3,5,6],['max',2,4,7,8]]

Comment: I wonder then why it doesn't work for me.. I'll have a deeper look, maybe because I'm directing the "if statement to a hash table with a codeword 'max', then a function is called to give the answer. I think I'll try to address that :)